# How do we unlock "locked urban chests" in Venetica?

Tags: venetica

I have been running around for quite a while but still haven't found a way or gained a skill that signifies the ability to unlock the urban chests present in iron ore mines. Anyone knows how can we unlock these chests? When I try to open them it just tells me they are locked and she shakes her head.

Comment: what do you do when you get to the room that has a coffin in it?

Comment: I don't understand which coffin you are talking about. <SPOILERS>.................See if you can switch to the twilight world and try the coffin. Later on you get the ability to lockpick so you might also want to try that (it kicks in automatically actually when you click). Last of all if nothing works you might want to see if you can break it with a hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you make it to Venice (Outer City District), head to the Old Temple immediately right of the Water Gateway Entrance. Go in, watch the cutscene. You'll learn the skill shortly after.

Once you've got the skill, you can backtrack and get the locked chests.

Comment: Thanks. This game has good gameplay but is somewhat lacking in proper explanations/hints/clues on these occasions. Half of the time I'm searching online to find what to do.

Comment: You're right. They've got the game essentially right, just missing some details.